# Nginx returns 404 when using Vue Router even with redirect

Tags: vue.js, nginx, vue-router, nginx-config

I have a problem using Vue Router with Nginx as a Webserver. I get error 404 if I refresh my App Component Page.

I configured my nginx-config like mentioned in the docs:
[Vue Router Doc](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)

And I use this configuration of my index.js for Vue Router:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from '../views/App.vue'
import Login from '../views/Login.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/app',
    name: 'App',
    component: App
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Login',
    component: Login
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: routes
})

export default router
```

In my Login-Component I am using `this.$router.push('app')` after logging in. This is working properly. My URL is changing to ..../app and I see my App Component. The problem is that I get error 404 after refreshing the page.

The Nginx error/access-logs show this error, because the Client tried to access the /app-location which does not exist.

My Nginx conf looks like this:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/rtmp.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile off;
        tcp_nopush on;
        #aio on;
        directio 512;
        #tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 60;
        #types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-auth-pam.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_auth_pam_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-dav-ext.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_dav_ext_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-echo.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_echo_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-geoip.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-subs-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_subs_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-upstream-fair.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_upstream_fair_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-xslt-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-mail.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_mail_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-rtmp.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_rtmp_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-stream.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/rtmp.conf:
rtmp {
  server {
    listen 1935;
    chunk_size 4096;
    application live {
      live on;

      record all;
      record_path ~/recording;
      record_unique on;

      #turn on hls
      hls on;
      #hls_continuous on;
      hls_path /var/www/stream/hls/;
      hls_fragment 3;
      hls_playlist_length 60;
      #disable consuming the stream from nginx as rtmp
      deny play all;

      #record off;
    }
  }
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

        #SSL Certificates
        ssl_certificate "mycert/cert.pem";
        ssl_certificate_key "mycert/privkey.pem";
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;

        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;

        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=315360000";

        index index.html;

        root /var/www/html/airspeed-rr-client/;

        server_name myservername;
        #return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

        location / {

                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

                if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                        #
                        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
                        #
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'authorization,DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
                        #
                        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
                        #
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
                        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                        return 204;
                }
                if ($request_method = 'POST') {
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'authorization,DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
                }
                if ($request_method = 'GET') {
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'authorization,DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
                }
        }
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/gunicorn:
server {
        listen 8000 ssl;
        server_name myserver;

        ssl_certificate "mycert/cert.pem";
        ssl_certificate_key "mycert/privkey.pem";
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;


        location / {
          include proxy_params;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

          proxy_redirect off;

          proxy_buffering off;

          proxy_cache off;

          if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        #
        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'x-access-token,authorization,DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        #
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'x-access-token,authorization,DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'x-access-token,authorization,DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
     }


          if (!-f $request_filename) {
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/pi/airspeed-rr-server/gunicorn.sock;
                break;
          }
        }
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/proxy_params:
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/hls:
server {
    listen 8080 ssl;

    ssl_certificate "mycert/cert.pem";
    ssl_certificate_key "mycert/privkey.pem";
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;

    server_name myserver;

    location /hls {

        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }

        types {
            application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
            video/mp2t ts;
        }

        root /var/www/stream/;

    }
}
```

Do I need to add all my router locations to the nginx conf? I thought the redirect should be sufficient for this task...

Entry from /var/log/nginx/error.log:

`2020/05/22 13:31:33 [error] 17379#17379: *41 open() "/var/www/html/myapproot/app" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

Comment: Added in Original Post above.

Comment: I updated the post with my complete nginx conf (I just changed my cert files and my servername for security reasons). As you can see there are other Server blocks but they all listen on other ports.

Comment: You are using `if` blocks inside a `location` block. Which is probably why `try_files` is not working as expected. See [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

Comment: Mh I am trying to change that. The problem is that if-blocks are needed for setting CORS properly. This is how many docs say how to handle CORS with Nginx.

Comment: maybe its because `/var/www/stream/` != `/var/www/html`?